# Remove UIImagePickerController from Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a CCLayer which I need to add a camera to, on top of that I need a custom button to close the camera overlayed onto of the camera. I eventually need to display CCSprites on top of it all, but first need to be able to dismiss the camera.

But when I click on the button, I get SIGABRT or BAD EXE errors depending on whether I use `[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] sendSubviewToBack:uip.view];` or `[uip.view removeFromSuperview];`

```
-(void) displayCamera
{

uip = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
uip.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
uip.showsCameraControls = NO;
uip.toolbarHidden = YES;
uip.navigationBarHidden = YES;
uip.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:uip.view];

UIButton *arrowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[arrowButton addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(arrowButtonClicked:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIImage *imgNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_next_norm.png"];
[arrowButton setImage:imgNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *imgPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_next_pressed.png"];
[arrowButton setImage:imgPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

arrowButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width - 48.0, screenSize.height - 37.0, 48.0, 37.0);

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:arrowButton];
}

-(void)arrowButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
 // close / hide camera 

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] sendSubviewToBack:uip.view];

// or maybe [uip.view removeFromSuperview];

// and then go to another scene

LoadingScene* scene = [LoadingScene sceneWithTargetScene:TargetSceneEndExperienceScene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is this line:

```
uip = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Using `autorelease` in this case doesn't work because the `UIImagePickerController` is not retained by it's view, so you need to make sure that you retain it yourself.  Instead of autoreleasing it, I would hold onto the reference to it, and then after you remove it from the view, I would release it then.  I've changed your code to show what I mean:

```
-(void) displayCamera
{

uip = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  // Don't autorelease it here
uip.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
uip.showsCameraControls = NO;
uip.toolbarHidden = YES;
uip.navigationBarHidden = YES;
uip.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:uip.view];

UIButton *arrowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[arrowButton addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(arrowButtonClicked:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIImage *imgNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_next_norm.png"];
[arrowButton setImage:imgNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *imgPressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_next_pressed.png"];
[arrowButton setImage:imgPressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

arrowButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenSize.width - 48.0, screenSize.height - 37.0, 48.0, 37.0);

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:arrowButton];
}

-(void)arrowButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
 // close / hide camera 

[uip.view removeFromSuperview];
[uip release];  // Release here
uip = nil;

// and then go to another scene

LoadingScene* scene = [LoadingScene sceneWithTargetScene:TargetSceneEndExperienceScene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];    
}
```